# Make a form submit to an email directly from a static site?

Tags: html

I'm in the process of making a static site. I've got a testimonial page in which there is a form to add testimonials that I want to send responses to a selected email. There is the html MAILTO function. But I don't much care for that feature as I feel many people wishing to submit a testimonial won't have outlook etc set-up to do so or won't be comfortable with it. I've been unable to find an alternative to this for a static site.

Is there an alternative? If so, what is it?

*Edit: I don't necessarily need it conveyed to an e-mail, any way to access the information submitted would be fine.

Comment: Use and iframe and a tool like JotForm. Also just a PHP script on a static site isn't very much, it can be done with basic PHP and can be emailed or sent to a database.

Comment: Excellent idea. I'm looking into JotForm now. I'm not versed in PHP. Can I get a example?

Comment: I guess if solved your problem i'll type up a quick answer and you could accept it?

Comment: Yes. Also add a example PHP, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool such as [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com/) or any other form service through and iframe, or sometimes you can embed it into the page and they handle the rest. If you want to do it the PHP way you can create a form and name the inputs with their respective names, then you can send the results to an email. You can use the following code to send an email, but you'll need to put your variables in there.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

If you're not looking to do much work with PHP, since it might get a bit complicated if you are new to PHP you might as well go with JotForm. You can also check out [Formstack](http://www.formstack.com/) and [Woofuu](http://www.wufoo.com/) if you're up for paying

Comment: Awesome. JotForm is a perfect tool for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Up voting the answer would be much appreciated ;)

Comment: There's also [FormSpree](https://formspree.io/), which is easy to use and set-up.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: your HTML:

```
<form action='mail.php' action='post'>
  <input type='text' id='inputName'>
  <textarea id='feedback'></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The shortest possible PHP script to mail the info from the form:

```
<? mail($to,$subject,print_r($_POST,true)); ?>
```

This will result in an email like this:

```
Array
(
   [inputName] => Name Entered
   [feedback] => Feedback entered
)
```

for $to you can use your email address, and the subject is pretty straight forward as well

Comment: I think you're missing the submit button, assuming the OP is fresh to PHP and maybe HTML you might as well add the submit